# How do i make this shopping list that has an add product button and an empty button

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make a cart page with 'empty cart' button and 'add to cart' button. I want to make the list so it adds under each other. In my code each time I press "add to shopping cart" it comes right beside each other with no spaces(instead of coming on the next line). What should I do?

How do I also make an 'empty cart' button once I have all the products added, is there a method to remove all the nodes in the cart using a function?

```js
 window.onload = start;
 function start()
 {
   console.log('start');
 }

 function addTo()
 {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += document.getElementById("txtProduct").value;
 }

 function empty()
 {

 }
```

```html
  <label>Product</label> <input type="text" id="txtProduct">

    <button onclick="addTo()">Add to shopping cart</button>
    <button onclick="empty()">Empty cart</button>

    <p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```js
window.onload = start;
 function start()
 {
   console.log('start');
 }

 function addTo()
 {
 var product = document.createElement("p");
 product.innerText = document.getElementById("txtProduct").value;;
 document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(product);  
 }

 function empty()
 {
document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = "";
 }
```

```html
<label>Product</label> <input type="text" id="txtProduct">

    <button onclick="addTo()">Add to shopping cart</button>
    <button onclick="empty()">Empty cart</button>

<div id="wrapper">
<p id="output"></p>

</div>
```

I added a wrapper div so you could clean it on "empty" action.
Also I used the JS `createElement` function to create a `<p>` element for each product, it's more clean and right than adding just text to element's innerHTML. That makes them line-seperated, too...

Comment: so with the js createElement, this will create whenever i type in and it will add to the list? and the <p> can this be other alphabet than p

Comment: and the appendchild do you know what it does?

Comment: `createElement` will create a HTML element, we chose `<p>` which is a paragraph (= newLine + text). We put the text into the `<p>` element and then appended this newly created element as a child to other element, which is actually the `<div>` wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Just change your addTo function like this:

```
function addTo() {
    var elem = document.createElement("p");
    elem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtProduct").value;
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(elem);
    document.getElementById("txtProduct").value = "";
 }
```

What this does is that every time you call the function, you create a p element with the value of txtProduct, it then appends the elem to the DOM and clear the value of txtProduct so you do not have to clear it manually each time you enter a value.

Then, change your empty function:

```
function empty() {
  document.getElementById("output").childNodes.forEach((node) => {
   node.innerHTML = "";
 })
}
```

This is the [jsbin test](https://jsbin.com/fubavedefi/edit?html,js,output)